# I want to categorize some data according to my rules that are not completely in accordance with my rules

Tags: python, group-by, categories, rules

I want to categorize some data according to my rules that are not completely in accordance with my rules.

```py
group = ((1, ["zt"]), (2, ["xjt"]), (3, ["ppt"]), (4, ["dpt"]), (5, ["sxb"]), (6, ["tmzt"]))

indata = [(1001,"zt_1"), (1002,"zt_2"), (1021,"tmzt_1"),(1023,"xjt_1"), (1244,"xjt_2")]
```

I want group by rules(group)

```
outdata = [(1, 1001,"zt_1", 1), (1, 1002,"zt_2", 2), (6, 1021,"tmzt_1", 1),(2, 1023,"xjt_1", 1), (2, 1244,"xjt_2", 2)]
```

outdata contain (group id, indata id, indata name, group inner sort)
but Not all the data are in accordance with my group rules.

output can also be a dict like

```
[{"group_id": 1, "image_id": 1001, "name": "zt_1", "sort_order": 1}, ...]
```

group is unique

Comment: will the 2nd item of every tuple in `group` be unique? looks like you should consider a different datastructure like a dictionary to make this easier to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this easier by creating an intermediate dictionary, which can be used to check which values should be kept in the result.

```
group = ((1, ["zt"]), (2, ["xjt"]), (3, ["ppt"]), (4, ["dpt"]), (5, ["sxb"]), (6, ["tmzt"]))

indata = [(1001,"zt_1"), (1002,"zt_2"), (1021,"tmzt_1"),(1023,"xjt_1"), (1244,"xjt_2")]

group_dict = {tup[1][0]: tup[0] for tup in group}
#Output:
{'zt': 1, 'xjt': 2, 'ppt': 3, 'dpt': 4, 'sxb': 5, 'tmzt': 6}

result = []
for tup in indata:
    key, val = tup[1].split("_")
    if key in group_dict:
        result.append((group_dict[key], *tup, int(val)))

print(result)
#Output:
[(1, 1001, 'zt_1', 1),
 (1, 1002, 'zt_2', 2),
 (6, 1021, 'tmzt_1', 1),
 (2, 1023, 'xjt_1', 1),
 (2, 1244, 'xjt_2', 2)]
```